# Setup IntelliJ to test android apps on Galaxy S4

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have just started learning Android app development and am using Intellij. up till now I have been using the Android virtual device.

I want to use my galaxy S4 or galaxy Tab in order to run/test my apps.

Have tried everything. 
How do I get this working??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the device debug drivers are installed, and that ADB is running. You can kick it off with `adb devices` at the command prompt.

I've found that in some situations trying to get a new device working you have to manually kill adb.exe in task manager and try again

Comment: I downloaded the debug drivers from the samsung website. I did killed adb in the task manager and restarted everything. Still nothing showing up on intelliJ

Comment: Got it working. 
I restarted everything and it is now working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please read "Setting up a Device for Development" here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html and come back with specific questions

Comment: I already went through all those things. when i try run the app using Intellij it doesn't pick up my device